# JQuery not working correctly on delay remove class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've spent a lot trying to figure it the way to make it work, and I've tried a lot of solutions but none of them worked for my case and I don't know why, because this is so simple!

What I want to make is when the website is loaded to add a specific class with display block for several seconds then remove it with Jquery.

Html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<style>
.loader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000000;
    background: red;
    display: none;
}

.hide{
    display: block;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="loader">hello</div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("loader").addClass("hide");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("loader").removeClass("hide");
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Can you look onto it for a solution, i like it clean even if it has no meaning.

Comment: $("loader") should be  $(".loader"), typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change the javascript code like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".loader").addClass("hide");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".loader").removeClass("hide");
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks worked, can't accept for now because low rep